# MySQL update table as result of SELECT in another table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to update my WordPress's avatars. I have a table `wp_commentmeta` which has some broken `meta_value`s.

I need to recalculate the values based on the `wp_comment` table's `comment_author_email`.

This query gets me a table with the comment ID and the new URL

```
SELECT 
   comment_id, 
   CONCAT("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/", MD5(comment_author_email)) AS url
   FROM `wp_comments` 
   WHERE comment_id IN
      (SELECT 
         comment_id FROM `wp_commentmeta` 
         WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'avatar' 
         AND `meta_value` LIKE 'invalid')
```

```
| comment_id | url                                   |
|------------|---------------------------------------|
| 1234       | https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ff... |
| 5678       | https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ab... |
| ....       |  ...                                  |
```

But how do I update `wp_commentmeta` based on that?

I *think* I want to loop through the results and run:

```
UPDATE `wp_commentmeta`
   SET `meta_value` = url
   WHERE `comment_id` = comment_id
   AND `meta_key` LIKE 'avatar' 
   AND `meta_value` LIKE 'invalid'
```

But how do I do that in a single query? Is this something where I can use a `JOIN`?

Comment: Yes, you can use joins in an update.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow - would you be able to give me a quick example?

Comment: I used update join once before, this tutorial was useful https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/ sorry I can't give it here as answer since I not sure about the wordpress database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that should put you in the right direction. I have not tested it, so I suggest you start a transaction and then check that it did the right thing before you commit.

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE wp_commentmeta AS m
JOIN wp_comments AS c USING (comment_id)
SET m.meta_value = CONCAT("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/", MD5(c.comment_author_email))
WHERE m.meta_key = 'avatar' AND m.meta_value = 'invalid';

...run some SELECT to double-check that it did what you want...

COMMIT;
```